# Angular2 Test (jasmine) mocking Service. Can't resolve all parameters for Service: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, testing, mocking

i am trying to mock following service to test my component:

Production:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService extends DtoService {
    // some not relevant stuff.
}

@Injectable()
export abstract class DtoService {
    constructor(private http: Http, private authHttp: AuthHttp) {}

    get() {
        return this.http.get(...);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'users',
    templateUrl: 'users.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['users.scss'],
    providers: [UserService]
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
    // etc
}
```

Test:

```
class MockUserService {
    public get(): Observable<User> {
        return Observable.of(new User({id: 1, email: 'user1@test.com'}));
    }
}

beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed
        .configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [UsersComponent],
            providers: [{provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService}]
        });
    this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UsersComponent);

}));
```

It is supposed to be the most classical use-case, right (see [angular test doc](https://angular.io/guide/testing))? But here I get the Error:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for UserService: (?, ?).
```

But UserService is not supposed to be instantiated at all. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you community!

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide in your stubed service's constructor `private http: Http, private authHttp: AuthHttp` or some mocked service of it.

Comment: It actually asks more questions about the test system of angular:
- Why does angular try to instantiate the stubed service if it is replaced by the stubing service?
- should my stubing service have the same constructor signature than the stubed one?
- isn't angular supposed to find http and authHttp by its own with the @Injectable() like in production?
- How can I pipe null, null for values to the constructor?
Thank you!

Comment: yep, you have to get the same constructors. that's why when you get such painfull service to stub i can recomand to spy them instead of stubing them. the angular documentation is realy clear about spying service, you may look it to solve your issue